# USART1_IRQHandler called continuously

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, interrupt, uart

I am using a STM32L071 chip on a custom devBoard. I need to receive certain characters on a UART, and set some flags if those characters come.

When I receive something on my UART, USART1_IRQHandler() function is called, I check `if ((USART1->ISR & USART_ISR_RXNE) == USART_ISR_RXNE)`, but after that the USART1_IRQHandler() function is called continuously. I set a breakpoint in that function and it is called continuously.
I tried checking all the sources that could call the interrupt, but none of them seem to trigger the   `__HAL_UART_GET_IT_SOURCE(&UartHandle, XX_IT_SOURCE)`

Here is my GPIO configuration

```
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

__HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE()
;

GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9;           //PA9 USART1 TX
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_USART1;
HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_9);
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10;        //PA10 UART1 RX
GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_USART1;
HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_10);
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

After that, I configure my UART

```
__HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_ENABLE();
UartHandle_RADIO.Instance = USART1;
UartHandle_RADIO.Init.BaudRate = 115200; // 9600;
UartHandle_RADIO.Init.WordLength = USART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
UartHandle_RADIO.Init.StopBits = USART_STOPBITS_1;
UartHandle_RADIO.Init.Parity = USART_PARITY_NONE;
UartHandle_RADIO.Init.Mode = USART_MODE_TX_RX;
UartHandle_RADIO.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;


if (HAL_UART_DeInit(&UartHandle_RADIO) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
}

if (HAL_UART_Init(&UartHandle_RADIO) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
}

HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART1_IRQn, 0, 0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
```

Before my main loop I call

```
__HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&UartHandle_RADIO, UART_IT_RXNE);
```

My interrupt function:

```
void USART1_IRQHandler(void) 
{

    if ((USART1->ISR & USART_ISR_RXNE) == USART_ISR_RXNE) {

        __HAL_UART_CLEAR_IT(&UartHandle, UART_IT_RXNE);
        //__HAL_UART_CLEAR_IT(&UartHandle, UART_CLEAR_OREF);
        g_ReceiveduChar = (uint8_t) USART1->RDR;

        if (g_ReceiveduChar == 0x3F) {
            firstCommandFlag = 0x01;
            g_ReceiveduChar = 0x0;

        } else if ((g_ReceiveduChar == 0x3E) && (firstCommandFlag == 0x01)) {
            requestReadings = 0x01;
            firstCommandFlag = 0x00;
            g_ReceiveduChar = 0x0;

        }
    }
}
```

I included the STCube HAL provided by ST.

Comment: This ISR doesn't make much sense - either you only expect RXNE as interrupt source, in which case there should be no if statement there. Or you expect all manner of interrupt sources (errors etc), in which case you need to clear all flags, not just RXNE.

Comment: Even if I remove the if statement, the problem is the same. The USART1_IRQHandler() function is called continuously

Comment: And when that happens, which flags are set? Any overrun or framing error flags etc?

Comment: In the ISR, the ORE flag is set.  In the CR1 register, the RXNEIE is the only interrupt flag set

Comment: Ok well I don't remember this specific part in detail, but you need to make sure that overruns do not trigger the interrupt. (Btw in general, STM32 often has DMA support, which is a much better option than repeated interrupts.)

Comment: In addition to what Lundin said, you don't clear the pending IRQ in the NVIC. Any interrupt example code I've seen has code for this. Try adding `HAL_NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(USART1_IRQn);`

Comment: The Overrun Error seems to be the problem. My IRQHandler now looks like this:  I check if the ORE flag, If that and the RXNE flag are set, i read the RDR register and clear ORE. If ORE is set, and RXNE is NOT set, i only clear ORE flag.   If ORE is not set, I inly read the RDR register